# @Autowired on a field and on a setter method

Tags: spring, autowired

I've had a weird situation while autowiring properties of my bean. @Autowired put on setter method doesn't work properly and field that corresponds to that setter returns me `NullPointerException` when I try to get access to some of it's methods. On the other hand, @Autowired put on field directly works fine.

What could be the reason of such a behavior and what is the difference between putting @Autowired on the field and field's corresponding setter?

Here is excerpt from my code:

```
private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate;

protected JdbcOperations getJdbcTemplate() {
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}
```

Here is from context:

```
<bean name="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="routingDataSource"/> 
</bean>
```

Thank you very much for explanations!

Answer (score 1):

If it works for field, it works for setter as well.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation

Most likely you missed something else. Did you by chance create the instance of this class yourself with `new` keyword while testing the setter injection? Or, `jdbcTemplate` was not present on context when you made the test of setter injection. There are many possibilities...

Comment: Thanks Sotirios, updated to 3.0.x. Couldn't find any more up to date.

Comment: You can put `current` where the version should be in the URL and you'll get the most current.